# Laravel + Eloquent : combine 2 tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to perform a query with Eloquent where I can get all the courses of an user.

Users have their courses because they are in some grade. So all courses of this grade will be included.

```
$user->grade->courses
```

Now I'd like to include some courses that are not in the user's grade thanks to the pivot table : users_courses. But I don't know how to query all tables at once using Eloquent.

[image]

**EDIT** : Here is what have

```
class Users extends Eloquent {
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Courses', 'users_courses', 'student_id', 'course_id');
    }

    public function grade()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Grades', 'grade_id');   
    }
}

class Courses extends Eloquent {
    public function grade()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Grades');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Users', 'users_courses', 'student_id', 'course_id');
    }
}

class Grades extends Eloquent {

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Courses', 'grade_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Users', 'grade_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the relationships in the models yet? As in adding belongsTo() or hasMany() in the models/ModelName.php file?

Comment: take a look at **[Eager Loading](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)**, something like `User::with('courses')->get();`

Comment: Try `User::with('courses', 'grade.courses')->get();`